# Many download requests eventually return 403: dailyLimitExceededUnreg

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm writing a Node.js application to download files from Google Drive. I'm using the googleapis npm package, and I'm authenticating using a service account. I'm assuming the authentication is being done correctly because I can see all my application's requests in the Drive API Metrics tab under Google Cloud Console. After a large number of downloads, the requests begin to fail with this response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

I am seeing these requests in Google Cloud Console as 403 responses. If I wait for a few hours and try again without modifying the code, the downloads begin to work again.

If I am not authenticating correctly, why do these requests appear in Google Cloud Console under my account? If I am actually authenticating correctly, why does the error message say this is an "unauthenticated" request, and is it possible to raise the quota? (none of the quotas listed for the Google Drive API in Google Cloud Console are anywhere close to being exceeded)

I'm using an adapted version of the authentication code in the googleapis documentation:

```
import { google } from 'googleapis'
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
const drive = google.drive('v3')

main()
async function main() {
  await initDriveAuth()
  await download('<file id>')
}

// This authenticates future requests using process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS,
// which contains the JSON key of a service account:
async function initDriveAuth() {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
  })

  google.options({
    auth: await auth.getClient()
  })
}

// This creates a download stream for the file with fileID
async function download(fileID: string) {
  return await drive.files.get({
    fileId: fileID,
    alt: 'media'
  }, {
    responseType: 'stream'
  })
}
```

my .env file looks like this:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./config/service_account_key.json
```

Comment: Please edit your question.  Include your code.   **Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.** means you are not sending authentication with your call.

Comment: @DaImTo I added my code, although my question is more about trying to understand the behavior of the Google Drive API, regardless of whether the call was sent with authentication, because the behavior of both cases doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The request is failing with that because at some point your not sending a valid access token probably because it has expired.   Again i really need to see your authorization code.  You should consider following this for the auth section https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: @DaImTo I don't think it is expiring because if I restart the application, it immediately begins to return the 403 responses. I already included all my authorization code; I just followed these instructions for authenticating with a service account: https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis#using-the-google_application_credentials-env-var

Comment: You're not using your authenticated client? You define `const drive = google.drive('v3')`, call `initDriveAuth()` and then don't do anything with it - you've declared `const auth` inside and then do nothing with the function and call `files.get` on the initial `drive` client which only has the version (v3) to go on

Comment: @RafaGuillermo setting auth in google.options makes it the global default for the library and will be used for all future requests: https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis#setting-global-or-service-level-auth In any case, I already tried directly adding the auth object on each request, and the behavior seemed to be identical.

Comment: Are you sure your download is being called after the Auth has been set? What if you change your await calls to `initDriveAuth().then(download('<file id>'))`?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo yes, the full version of the code calls download many times, and it has successfully downloaded files for over an hour before the 403 error happens. The code you suggested is equivalent.

Comment: Hey, isn't that a `cwd` problem? Your google config location is relative - it would be better to set it to an absolute path maybe?